# How to open external website and get its html content in asp.net using c# or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to open external website in new window and get its html content in asp.net using c# or JavaScript

```
var win = window.open('http://www.google.com'/* '../test.html'*/, "Popup", "width=550,height=300");
        var hm = "not set";

       
        //var hm = win.document.getElementsByClassName("hmdiv")[0].textContent;
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
           
            try {
               hm = win.document.getElementById("divhm").value;
   
            } catch (e) {

            }
            if (win.closed) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                alert('closed: ' + hm);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is only to get content from another page (and not *need* to display it in a new window), then perhaps this NuGet package will do what you need:  [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp).

Here is example code from the GitHub page:

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
var address = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Big_Bang_Theory_episodes";
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
var document = await context.OpenAsync(address);
var cellSelector = "tr.vevent td:nth-child(3)";
var cells = document.QuerySelectorAll(cellSelector);
var titles = cells.Select(m => m.TextContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

make ajax call to retrieve the html.

$.ajax({
url: "Website url", success: function(result){

```
  $("#dvWebsite").html(result);
```

});